# Trying to understand simple bit states

Tags: computer-architecture

I am trying to understand bits, operations and masking. I have a hard time to get this thing into my head. I have tried to read at many different websites without luck.

I have 8 states, going from 1 to 8:

```
state 1 = 0001
state 2 = 0010
state 3 = 0011
state 4 = 0100
state 5 = 0101
state 6 = 0110
state 7 = 0111
state 8 = 1000
```

Now I want to get state 1, 3, 6 and 8. I am unsure how to set this state in the bits. Either I can do this:

```
state 1 = 0001
state 3 = 0011
state 6 = 0110
state 8 = 1000
```

Which would turn out like this:

```
combinedStates = 1111
```

The problem is, if I send in this, state 5 will get triggered as well as:

```
state 1 = 0001
state 3 = 0011
state 5 = 0101
state 6 = 0110
state 8 = 1000
```

Because both state 5 and 6 has a 1 in the same place. The second thing would be to add all the state numbers together (1, 3, 6 and 8, which is 18):

```
combinedStates = 0001 0010 (18)
```

But then looking at state 6 would not work as:

```
state 6 = 0110
combinedStates = 0001 0010
```

There will be a missing 1.

How would I proceed if I want to get states 1, 3, 6 and 8: combine their bits, or add them all together and use that one's bit value? Any other approach? Any operand I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use one bit per state for a total of 8 bits:

state1 = 0000 0001
state2 = 0000 0010
...
state8 = 1000 0000

Then you can just `bitwise or` (or add) them together. Many programming languages have a datastructure for "bitsets" that can help with this, especially if you have more bits than fit in a simple integer. Your example with just 8 states fits in a typical int, so you don't really need such a data structure.

Comment: Thanks, what if I want more, for instance one for each letter in the alphabet? Do I need bit sets then? What if this support is not available for me, do I have to create this myself by combing several bits or bytes?

Comment: Letters fit in a 64-bit number. If you need more than fits in one number you need more numbers. A bitset datastructure helps managing all those numbers. If you can't find a library that you can use, you need to implement your own, it's not that hard.